# Whats wrong with quicksort3

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

What's wrong with my 3-way partition quicksort? When input data less then 100000 it work normal time. When input data = 100000 it work around 9 sec.
I use Dijkstra 3-way partition. If input data consists of a large number of identical elements everything work normal, when input data random work too slow.

```
 static void randomizedQuickSort(int[] a, int l, int r) {
    if (l >= r) {
        return;
    }

    int[] m = Partition3(a, l, r);
    randomizedQuickSort(a, l, m[0] - 1);
    randomizedQuickSort(a, m[1] + 1, r);
}

private static int[] Partition3(int[] nums, int l, int r) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int k = random.nextInt(r - l + 1) + l;
    int mid = nums[k];
    int m1 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int m2 = r;


    while (m1 <= m2) {
        if (nums[m1] < mid) {
            swap(nums, i, m1);
            i++;
            m1++;
        } else if (nums[m1] > mid) {
            swap(nums, m1, m2);
            m2--;
        } else {
            m1++;
        }
    }

    return new int[]{i, m2};
}
```

Comment: Creating a `new Random` is pretty expensive. I would create one and re-use it or use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`

Comment: I did what you said, but my perfomance did not increase

Comment: Considering plotting a graph of performance over n (and attach it to the question). It sounds like there is a 'a difference from expected performance' around N1 < 100k < N2, and a graph could help clarify such anomalies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something wrong as the number of swaps is O(n^2) If you count the number of calls to `swap` you get something like (the first number is the number of elements)

```
10000: Took 0.078000 seconds, and 33432534 swaps
20000: Took 0.291000 seconds, and 166934755 swaps
40000: Took 1.102000 seconds, and 702291723 swaps
80000: Took 4.482000 seconds, and 2837543629 swaps
160000: Took 17.590000 seconds, and 11373050608 swaps
```

The problem is the lines

```
int m1 = 0;
int i = 0;
```

where you sort from the start of the array on every sort.

```
int m1 = l; // sort from the start of the section.
int i = l;
```

The full version is....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int t = 100_000;  t <= 100_000_000; t *= 10) {
        int[] nums = new int[t];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        swaps = 0;
        randomizedQuickSort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++)
            if (nums[0] > nums[1])
                throw new AssertionError();
        System.out.printf("%d: Took %f seconds, and %d swaps%n", t, time / 1e3, swaps);
    }
}

static void randomizedQuickSort(int[] a, int l, int r) {
    if (l >= r) {
        return;
    }

    long m = Partition3(a, l, r);
    int m0 = (int) (m >> 32);
    int m1 = (int) m;
    randomizedQuickSort(a, l, m0 - 1);
    randomizedQuickSort(a, m1 + 1, r);
}

static final Random random = new Random();
static long swaps = 0;

private static long Partition3(int[] nums, int l, int r) {
    int k = random.nextInt(r - l + 1) + l;
    int mid = nums[k];
    int m1 = l;
    int i = l;
    int m2 = r;


    while (m1 <= m2) {
        if (nums[m1] < mid) {
            swap(nums, i, m1);
            i++;
            m1++;
        } else if (nums[m1] > mid) {
            swap(nums, m1, m2);
            m2--;
        } else {
            m1++;
        }
    }

    return ((long) i << 32) | m2;
}

private static void swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
    int t = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = t;
    swaps++;
}
```

prints

```
100000: Took 0.018000 seconds, and 2032183 swaps
1000000: Took 0.168000 seconds, and 24872604 swaps
10000000: Took 1.709000 seconds, and 287681791 swaps
100000000: Took 19.015000 seconds, and 3353327832 swaps
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is working correctly.